# xlwings how to seprate py and excel file?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am new to xlwings and I want to use py file as a calculation engine for multiple excel workbooks.

So I want to put py file in a fixed folder such as C:\pycal\mycalculation.py
and use different excel files to link to this py file.
my problem is:
in excel, how to import and run python in a different folder;
and how to pass the path of the excel to python. in python, how to receive the path of the calling excel?

Comment: Last I checked, Excel cannot "import and run" Python code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to add the according folder `C:\pycal` as your `PYTHONPATH` in the xlwings settings. This is mentioned as a Note on the [Quickstart](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#macros-call-python-from-excel) guide as well as documented under [Settings](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/addin.html#user-settings).